O que vamos fazer com a tag Selenium?
Há algum tempo, nós decidimos mover as perguntas selenium para tag selenium-webdriver, mas algo que tenho percebido é que quase todas as perguntas são ruins.
No geral, é visível que quase nenhuma pergunta com a tag é útil para a comunidade se não para o próprio OP. Além de compartilharem um padrão de votos negativos, quase¹ todas é sobre não achar um elemento, não conseguir clicar em X, não conseguir escrever em Y, etc.
Além disso, o Selenium é muito usado para fins maliciosos e não como uma ferramenta de testes. Não acho legal termos conteúdo auxiliando pessoas à explorarem sistemas de forma mal intencionada.
São muitas perguntas deste gênero na tag. A maioria estão fechadas, e as que não estão, são inúteis e compartilham pontuação negativa no site.
Em suma, o que devemos fazer com esse monte de perguntas? Qual caminho devemos tomar?

¹ quando menciono "quase", é porque não encontrei nenhuma pergunta boa com a tag.


O problema não é a tag em si, e sim o fato de sequer seguirem as instruções da própria tag. Isso é um problema generalizado, tem tags que atraem coisas melhores e outras piores, mas o que manda é o escopo. Tag é consequência. Eu ficaria feliz se esse problema fosse só nessa :D

O ponto é: quase nenhuma pergunta da tag respeita a descrição da mesma. Quando menciono "quase", é porque não encontrei nenhuma pergunta boa com a tag.

Eu conseguiria listar uma outra série de tags que acontece o mesmo, vou evitar pra não gerar discussão fora do tema da pergunta. Mas o buraco é mais embaixo - entretanto, é um problema conhecido e que já é tratado rotineiramente. E eliminar a tag não adianta, as perguntas vão vir da mesma forma, só vai mudar o fato de estarem sem a tag.

E quais são as possíveis soluções e obstáculos para cada uma delas?

Negativo e voto de fechar. O obstáculo é ter a pontuação para os votos, o que é bem simples de obter (no seu caso o obstáculo já foi vencido com sobra). Quase sempre essas duas coisas são as melhores ferramentas para filtrar conteúdo, independe da tag. O resto o sistema praticamente cuida automaticamente. E se alguém com pontuação necessária notar alguma pergunta mais velha já fechada e razoavelmente negativada, que por alguma razão não foi "coletada" pelo sistema, pode usar o voto para remover.

Não há uma solução específica pra cada tag, o problema é o mesmo para todos os casos e não tem solução, pelo menos nada implementado, apesar de já ter diversas discussões aqui com ideais interessantes. O que dá pra fazer é remediar com negativos e fechando, tratando o sintoma, em vez de curar a doença. Quanto ao seu uso indevido, não é só com o Selenium, eu mesmo aprendi a fazer SQL Injection lendo sobre como se proteger do mesmo numa pergunta aqui, não podemos controlar como o conhecimento que compartilhamos será usado. Se não foi feito, eu deixaria as tags como sinônimos
